# Name and date range conflict

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, range

I'm working on a project and want to calculate in excel whether the date range would conflict for a specific user.

For example `"employee" Bill Smith` (cell B2) has a project from `10/17/2018` (Cell C2) to `10/24/2018` (Cell D2). If I enter a new project for the user from `10/18/2018` (Cell C3) to `10/22/2018` (Cell D3), I want it to flag a conflict.

How can this be done to match the name from column B to show a conflict highlighted in column E?

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1371884/edit) to show us some sample data and expected output? It would help us make suggestions that work for you

Comment: The numbers in your example do not follow an easily identifiable logical pattern. You have a start and end date but only want to flag dates that fall within (start+1) through (end-2)?

Answer (score 1):

You might find a simpler formula, but here is one. First, sort the rows by employee and start date. Then use a formula to check whether the start date is less than the end date on the rows above (for the same employee).

If *n* is the number of rows above (for the same employee), then the formula is `=IF(n=0, False, C6<MAX(OFFSET(D6, -n, 0, n, 1)))`. The way to calculate *n* is `COUNTIF(OFFSET(B6, -ROW(B6)+1, 0, ROW(B6)-1, 1), B6)`.

The entire formula in cell E6 is `=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B6, -ROW(B6)+1, 0, ROW(B6)-1, 1), B6)=0, FALSE, C6<MAX(OFFSET(D6, -COUNTIF(OFFSET(B6, -ROW(B6)+1, 0, ROW(B6)-1, 1), B6), 0, COUNTIF(OFFSET(B6, -ROW(B6)+1, 0, ROW(B6)-1, 1), B6), 1)))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**My solution has different approach. Formula checks conflict in dates if Employee names are  duplicate.**

*Formula checks conflict in Dates for `Adam` in Row `38 & 39` but not for `Adam & Sam` in Row `39 & 40` and so that not for `Sam & Harry`.*

[image]

**How it works:**

Write this formula in cell `D39` & fill down.

```
=IF(AND(A39=A38),IF(OR(B39>=B38,C39<=C38),"Yes","No"),"Diff. Name")
```

- *First part of the Formula checks whether names are similar or not if Yes then checks conflict in Dates.*
- For New names Formula returns caption `Diff. Name` & ignores Date conflict check.

Comment: Your solution works for consecutive rows only, it doesn't detect conflicts in earlier rows, I think that's also the intention.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, thanks for observation,, the Formula check from Row 39 onwards till for Harry in Row 44. Since Row 38 has the First record so that I've skipped it,,,.

Comment: If you enter a record for Sam into row 45 conflicting with his last row, your formula won't find it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, if I enter `Sam's record (is in Row 40)` again in `Row 45` formula in cell `D45` will show 'Diff. Name` and if `Sam recod (from Row 41 & 42)` in `Row 46 & 47` Formula will show `Yes` for Conflict in Cell `D46 & D47`.. and i think this what OP is looking for !! Any valuable suggest to 
 alter Formula !!

Comment: **Cont...** OP wants to check Conflict between Dates for Duplicate Names and the @scenography has opted the same method what I did .